# mvn command line request failing: mvn -Dsurefire.skipAfterFailure=1 test

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am able to get the functionality via a POM file adjustment, but not via command line.
What am I doing wrong?

Windows powershell command:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.skipAfterFailure=1 test
```

The error is response is this:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".skipAfterFailure=1".
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, proces
s-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

POM file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I can get it to work by adding

```
        <configuration>
            <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
        </configuration>
```

after the plugin version, so why I can't I get it to work from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is wrong, it has to be `mvn "-Dsurefire.skipAfterFailure=1" test` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is partly that PowerShell requires a backtick to precede the -D.
This command does not produce any error; however it still doesn't work.

```
mvn `-Dsurefire.skipAfterFailure=1 test
```

In a regular Windows CLI, no backtick is required.

Why does this command still not work?

Comment: I wrote the command wrong. It should have the word "Count" after "Failure".
mvn `-Dsurefire.skipAfterFailureCount=1 test